# Can you match a single character only that's within parenthesis for replacement using regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a weird case where the only real tool I have to use is Notepad++ without some heavy lifting, and I have a `|` delimited text file that has `|`s in the text that I need to remove.

Each `|` that I need to remove falls within parenthesis, so the text patterns look like this:

(123 | 456) (11.1 | 11.2)

...and so on.

My ideal result would be removing the |s contained within ()s and replacing with a -, so:

(123 - 456) (11.1 - 11.2)

So far I have:

`\(.*\|.*\)`

That matches each set of parenthesis that contains a | reliably, but I can't figure out a way to just match the `|` itself for replacement. Any ideas?

Comment: are `|` only in parenthesis or are there some not in parenthesis that you want to keep?

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following regex in notepad++

***find what:*** `([^|]*)\|([^)]*\))`

***Replace with:*** `$1-$2`

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/alCz9M/1)

***Explanation of regex:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```
([^|]*)   ##Creating 1st capturing group here, which has everything till | comes.
\|        ##Matching literal | here.
([^)]*\)) ##Creating 2nd capturing group here, which has everything till ) here including ).
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
(\([^()|]*)\|(?=[^()]*\))
```

and replace with `$1-`. *Details*:

- `(\([^()|]*)` - Group 1: `(` char and then zero or more chars other than `(`, `)` and `|`
- `\|` - a `|` char
- `(?=[^()]*\))` - there must be zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` char immediately to the right of the current location

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qtef0Y/1) and the demo screenshot below:

[image]

If you have multiple pipes (like in `(123 | 456 | 23) (11.1 | 11.2 | 788 | 6896)`):

```
(\G(?!^)|\()([^()|]*)\|(?=[^()]*\))
```

But now, replace with `$1$2-`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qtef0Y/2). This is compatible with some other common text editors, hence I did not suggest using a pattern with `\K` (see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qtef0Y/3)).

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this code,  which is a bit safe to use,  but a little long code ....

Find: `(\(\d+[. \d]*)[|](?=[ \d.]*\))`
Replace All: `$1-`

Updated
[image]

Comment: You could shorten your current pattern to `(\(\d+[. \d]*)[|](?= \d)` as the last part is optional and to assert digits, asserting just a single digit this way would suffice. Note that your current pattern does not make sure that there is a closing parenthesis, see https://regex101.com/r/1eaz88/1 If there should be a closing parenthesis, then you can account for that in the lookahead, see https://regex101.com/r/toRz8r/1

Comment: @fourth bird,  thank you sir,  I updated the my question , and made also changes in the sample, ,,,,,,,,    `(123  |  456) (11.1 | 11.2)`

`(123|456) (11.1|11.22)
`
`(123 |456) (11.1| 11.2)
`
`(123| 456) (11.1 |11.22)
`  also a screenshot highlighted result of code